# creating multiple Django model fields

Tags: django, django-models

I need to create 100 same fields in Django model. Maybe there is the simple way of doing this or I need to add it like this:

```
    Field1 = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    Field2 = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    Field3 = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    ...
```

?

Comment: guess you are doing it wrong.

Comment: I don't believe you need this. I hope it will be wrong database design. What do you want to do with this design?

Comment: You might want brush your concepts on DB Normalization: http://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php

Comment: @Bulva I'm importing data form google spreadsheet, and in that sheet there are 160 columns. So I need that much columns in my DB

Comment: You can't create codelists and divide this spreadsheet? I have never seen table with 160 columns and I am working with really big databases. I really hope that it is possible to divide spreadsheet to multiple tables.

Answer (score 0):

If your columns count are 100+. I advice you to use Django `JsonField` and save data like JsonFormat
for more information please read this link
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield